# Enum field filtration in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, filter, enums

I need to add a drop-down menu that filtrates with enum values from the table. Instead of that it gets the values from the rows.  Any and all help gratefully received.

This is what I have managed to get so far.

View:

```
<div>
    <span>
        <select class="mb-2">
            <option value="Status" disabled selected>Status</option>
                @foreach ($status_filter as $key => $status)
                   <option value="{{ $key }}">
                    {{$status}}
                   </option>
                @endforeach
        </select>
    </span>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
 $status_filter = Competition::pluck('status');
        $request->flash();
        return view('competition.index', compact('competitions', 'status_filter'));
```

This is what I need to get from the migration:

```
$table->enum('status',['inactive','to_push','active'])->default('inactive');
```

Comment: Can you explain more? Do you want to retrieve enum values from the table's column (which is used in migration) or distinct values from ```status``` colum from the table?

Comment: @SazzadHussain I want to use the 3 enum values to filter my results. But instead of that, it fills my drop-down with values from the table. I need to find a way to get the enums and use them as filters

Comment: Try this: https://laravel-tricks.com/tricks/get-enum-values-from-database. If it solves your problem, I will post it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @SazzadHussain suggested adding this block of code inside my model class solved the issue.

```
  public static function getPossibleEnumValues($table, $column) {
      $type = DB::select(DB::raw("SHOW COLUMNS FROM $table WHERE Field = '{$column}'"))[0]->Type ;
      preg_match('/^enum\((.*)\)$/', $type, $matches);
      $enum = array();
      foreach( explode(',', $matches[1]) as $value )
      {
        $v = trim( $value, "'" );
        $enum = Arr::add($enum, $v, $v);
      }
      return $enum;
    }
```

After that getting it from my Controller like that:

```
$enumoption = Competition::getPossibleEnumValues('competitions','status');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can grab those enum values from the table. But there is no direct way. You have to use laravel query builder using raw.

```
$statusValues = DB::select(DB::raw("SHOW COLUMNS FROM competitions WHERE Field = 'status' "))[0]->Type;
$matches = array();
preg_match('/^enum\((.*)\)$/', $statusValues, $matches);
$enumValues = array();
foreach( explode(',', $matches[1]) as $value )
{
  $v = trim( $value, "'" );
  $enumValues = $v;
}

print_r($enumValues)
```

Answer (score 0):

If i got it right you want to make a filter for status like listing all active ou inactive. I think the easiest way to do this is add a query on your variable `$status_filter` on the controller. Something like:  `$status_filter = Competition::where('status', 'active')->pluck('status');`